# wrong in date comparison

Tags: php, datetime

```
$ips = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/visitors.txt");
$arr = explode(",",$ips);

$today =  strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

for ($n = 0, $max = count($arr); $n <= $max; $n++) {
 $visArr = explode("#",$arr[$n]);
 $visDate = strtotime($visArr[1]); //$visArr[1] = 2011-12-27 14:10:45
 if($visDate < $today){
    unset ($arr[$n]);   
 }
}
 print_r($arr); //empty array!
```

data stored like that

```
 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#2011-12-27 11:56:24,

 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#2011-12-28 11:56:24,
```

the result is not correct when i do compare for visitor date, may i know what's wrong with it?

EDIT: i fixed up my code and still give an empty array when compare two date!! any advice??

Comment: In line 4 I see $arrr which is never declared.

Comment: Have you stepped through it to check what the value of $visDate is?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong with it, but here are the most obvious things:

- `$arr` is being exploded by `,\r\n` meaning the commas will no longer be in any of the resulting array elements, because delimiters are discarded (unless there is more to the data than what you originally posted).
- You aren't actually using `$key` in the first `foreach` loop, so you should probably just omit it.
- `$arrr` is being constantly overwritten in the first loop, meaning it will only contain the comma-delimited data from the last element of `$arr` when the loop is done.  Because your trailing commas are removed by the previous call to `explode()`, this is likely to be an array of nothing at this point.
- You're using the `count()` function in the second loop condition.  The count doesn't change, so you should put this either before the loop itself or in the first part like this:

  `for ($n = 0, $max = count($arrr); $n <= $max; $n++) {`
- You're using `<=` in the second loop, so you're doing an extra unneeded iteration.  The maximum index for an array of `n` elements is `n - 1`.  You should use `<` in this case, because `$arrr[count($arrr)]` is not defined.

Comment: i fixed up my code but still give an empty array when i compare two dates!

Comment: i have modified my post, take a look!

Comment: `strtotime(time())` is not correct.  You most likely want `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` instead.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?  There is probably an easier way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: to calculate last 24 hours visitors, i don't want to use MySQL db!

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma first then **strtotime**

```
$visDate = strtotime(trim($visArr[1], ","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummm....

```
$today =  strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

You make PHP generate a timestamp, format it to a string, then parse it back to a timestamp... Why not simply have

```
$today = time();
```

Comment: This makes code difficult to read and is an obvious waste of resources, but it actually works.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work, but yeah, it's a major waste of resources. This kind of construct is usually a sign of cargo cult programming.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as suggested here you must do:

```
$today = time();
```

to get current time in seconds since Epoch.

You're getting an empty array in the end because of this faulty comparison:

```
if($visDate < $today)
```

This condition will **always return true** because `$today` variable contains current time and your visitor log file has historical visitor's records which is obviously **less than** current timestamp.

If you just want your final array to show visitors of **last 24 hours only** then your condiction should be:

```
if(($today-$visDate) > 86400)
```

84600 is no of seconds in a day.